# Extract first value in boolean search string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to be able to control the hierarchy of elements I extract from a search string.

Specifically, in the string "425 million won", I would like to extract "won" first, but then "n" if "won" doesn't appear.

I want the result to be "won" for the following:

```
stringr::str_extract("425 million won", "won|n")
```

Note that specifying a space before won in my regex is inadequate because of other limitations in my data (there may not necessarily be a space between "million" and "won").  Ideally, I would like to do this using regex, as opposed to if-else clauses because of performance considerations.

Comment: "do this using regex [...] because of performance considerations" since when do regex mean good performances? They're a handy tool, but rarely an efficient one. In this case I'd expect a solution with a single regex to have terrible performances, especially compared to a plain-text search.

Answer (score 3):

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyCxpCS1KE/BRldBKU7D3krDXrE8P09TT1MrJsYbyAdyavI0lbiKwSpMjEwVcjNzcjLz8xSAMkpcuSDh9KLU9NSKgiINqGE6xToFqUU5tiFBoa6aXEDJ3MSS5IzUYo1inVzN6GjD2Nj//wE)

```
pattern <- "^(?:(?!won).)*\\K(?:won|n)"
s <- "425 million won"
m <- gregexpr(pattern,s,perl=TRUE)
regmatches(s,m)[[1]]
```

#### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:(?!won).)*` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character except instances where `won` proceeds
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `(?:won|n)` Match either `won` or `n`

Comment: chwheels, what is the procedure by which a string is extracted in my example.  That is to say, since I specify won first in the string, why isn't "won" in the output?  Just trying to see if I can keep the script simple.

Comment: @matsuo_basho it's because you're getting the `n` from `million`. It's returning the first match. This answer doesn't care for that `n` since it's going to look for `won` first and if it can't find it, it'll look for `n`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extend on the code you already have:

```
 na.omit(str_extract("420 million won", c("won", "n")))[1]
```